# Why first paragraph not taking this style p:first-child?

Tags: css

Why first paragraph not taking this style `p:first-child`

```
#content p:first-child {color:#4C4C4C;
font-size:1.2em;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:1.8;
margin-bottom:0.5em;}


<div id="content">
 <h1>Welcome</h1>
   <p>first paragraph</p>
   <p>second paragraph</p>
   <p>third paragraph</p>
</div>
```

How to select first paragraph from css?

Comment: Cause IE does not like pseudo elements

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While the previous answers have already defined the problem (that the `p` isn't the first child of the parent `div`), here's a solution to your problem, to target the first `p` that follows a `h1`, depending on your browser:

```
h1 + p { /* styles any paragraph that immediately follows a h1 element */ }
```

Comment: Very good point. If he's lucky that'll work for him across the board. +1

Comment: Well, this seemed the best pure-css method; though obviously applying a class of `.first` (or whatever) to the first paragraph is more cross-browser compatible. Compatibility seems okay (for almost all but IE6, with some problems for IE7 and IE8 *as* IE7): http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 27):

You're looking for the `:first-of-type` psuedo selector!
So, you'd do this to get that first paragraph:

```
#content p:first-of-type
```

Answer (score 4):

The selector matches any p element which is the first child of its parent.

In this case the p is the second child of its parent.

Have a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: this is the best explanation for me

Answer (score 0):

the content of P isn't its first child - from what I've seen a tag such as   or  would be the first child not the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

Could always just assign a class to every first paragraph -  full proof.

```
p.indent{
text-indent:50px;
   }
```